# Hamilton-like paths in digraph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

We are given digraph with two (possibly the same) vertices - let's call them S and F. We are also given some set of vertices W (possibly empty, possibly consisting of all vertices of digraph). We don't know whether graph is connected in any sense. The task is to find a path from S to F (possibly with repetitions of vertices and edges) passing through all vertices from W. Certainly there might be no such path.

My question is: how can we implement such search effectively? Intuition tells (but it might be wrong) that i need some modification of DFS, presumably maintaining a check of how many times we have already visited any edge. I think that we never need to pass through an edge more than 2 times. Unforunately i don't see any heuristic which may simplify the search since we even don't know whtether graph is connected. Any tips / links / (best of all - algorithm in pseudocode) will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. 1

To illustrate the problem, here's an example: we need a path from S to F passing through C. One possible answer is  S -> C -> S -> B -> F.
[image]

P. S. 2
Unfortunately i don't know whether there is any special name for such paths. This problem seems to be similar with Hamilton-path search problem except for the following: we're given start and end vertices of the path; the path needn't be simple. May be we can somehow apply Hamilton-path search algorithm but i have no idea how.

Comment: Do you want a shortest path or just any path?

Comment: @Casteels Any path.

Comment: Which Hamiltonian-path search algorithm are you referring to? There isn't an efficient (polynomial time) Hamiltonian-path search algorithm for $general$ graphs that we know of since NP=P is still an open problem...

Answer (score 0):

Since all you want is a path, I believe this problem is in $NPC$. Idea of proof:

Our problem under consideration is $A=\{(G,s,f,W):G$ has a path $\pi$ from $s$ to $f$ such that for every vertex $v$, $v\in W\implies v\in\pi\}$.

Then given such a pair $(G,s,f,W)$ and a path $\pi^*$, we can verify $\pi^*$ is a desired path in polynomial time. Hence $A\in NP$. Recall that for any $C\in NPC$, if $B\in NP$, then $B\leq_p C$, where $X\leq_p Y\iff$ there exists a total polynomial time $g$ such that $x\in X\iff g(x)\in Y$. So to show $A\in NPC$ we want to show $A\equiv_p C$ for some $C\in NPC$.  That is, $A\leq_p C$ and $C \leq_p A$.

Following your intuition let, $C=$ HAMILTONIAN_CIRCUIT (Denoted as $H$).Since $H\in NPC$, $A\leq_p H$ so now we just need to show $H\leq_p A$.

Suppose we are given an instance of $H$, $x=G$, for some $G=(V,E)$. Assume $G$ is not the empty graph (everything is trivial if it is) so $V$ contains at least one vertex, say $v_1$. We take $g$ to be the function that takes $x$ to $(G',s,f,W)$, where $s=f=v^*$ for some newly added $v^*\notin V$, $W=V$, and $G'=(V\cup\{v^*\}, E'=E\cup\{v_1v^*, v^*v_1\})$. Then if $x\in H$, there would exist a Hamiltonian circuit in $G$, specifically a circuit starting ending at $v_1$. Hence, there exists a path in $g(x)$ starting at $S$ going to $v_1$ then following the circuit back to $v_1$ then back to $f$. Since $W=V$ and $s,f$ are adjacent to $v_1$, then $g(x)\in A$.

Likewise, if $g(x)\in A$, then there is a path, $\pi'$, going from $S$ to $v_1$ and back to $v_1$ to $f$ since $s, f$ are only adjacent to $v_1$. But $\pi'$ must touch every vertex in $W=V$ so the path from $v_1$ to $v_1$ is a Hamiltonian circuit. Hence,$(V,E)=G$ has a Hamiltonian circuit so $x\in H$.

Thus, $H\leq_p A$ and $A\leq_p H$ so $A\equiv_p H$ so $A\in NPC$.

This means if you could find an "efficient" algorithm for this (generally considered polynomial time), you would win a million dollars! This is because it's an open question whether or not there are any $NPC$ problems that are also polynomial time (P=NP). Good luck! :)